# On adjective days, when to use の

Tags: particle-の, adjectives

Given the two sentences,
寒い日は温泉に行きます。雪の日は温泉に行きます。
Why does "on cold days" not need the の, but "on snowy days" it does? It appears most other adjectives also require the の, with the exceptions I've so far found being hot and cold.

Comment: Do you know how to recognize the difference between a noun and verb in Japanese?

Comment: @A.Ellett Honestly no other than some very basic things like るverbs, but that's something I'm starting to work towards. So far I've been basically just WK for kanji, and Duo/other apps for vocab and basic sentence structure examples, but none of that really explains these types of differences (which became very obvious as soon as it was explained).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the sentences  寒い日は温泉に行きます and 雪の日は温泉に行きます, the words 寒い and 雪 are different parts of speech.   Hence the differ structure used.

寒い means cold and is an adjective.

雪 is a noun. It means snow, not snowy.  In order to say a snowy day, you basically say "day of snow" 雪の日.

You can see this same structure in other phrases: 雨の日, a rainy day (more literally, a day of rain).

With adjectives, you do not put の between the adjective and the noun.  暑い is an adjective meaning hot.  暑い日 is a hot day.
If you said 暑いの日, this would be ungrammatical.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a ton of sense. I was getting too hung up on the translation to English being given as "rainy day" or "snowy day", I was thinking of it as an adjective even though I know the kanji itself is a noun.

Comment: In English we indeed sometimes say "snow day" which is even more confusing!

Comment: @Fattie Indeed. But usually a "snow day" refers not so much to a snowy day as it does to a day when you cancel something: like school or close a business because the streets are impassable or something.  Depending on where you are in the country (thinking States and Canada) that could just mean slick roads to a full blown blizzard.

Comment: quite true, @A.Ellett